# String Split using struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I like to split the string in my `view.jsp` page using struts2. Please help me out to solve this issue. I would like to split the string value using comma in `languagesKnown` which I get value from Database.

for example `languagesKnown` contains string like `"tamil,English,Malayalam"`. So I like to split the string using struts2

```
  <div class="personal-row1" style="width:90.4%;">
      <i class="icon-align-left icon-grey1">
      </i>
    <span class="blue1">
   Languages Known:
     </span>

     <!--<span class="price free"><span>Free</span></span>-->
          <span class="lang-tab">
          <s:property value="languagesKnown"/> </span>
           <span class="lang-tab">
           Tamil
           </span>
            <span class="lang-tab">
          Hindi
           </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string using struts 2 tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996543/how-to-split-a-string-using-struts-2-tags)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because it's older than a link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `split` method in OGNL expression

```
<s:iterator value='languagesKnown.split(",")'/> 
   <span class="lang-tab"><s:property/></span>
</s:iterator>
```