# How to split a string using struts 2 tags?

Tags: java, struts2, tags, split

For Example:

```
String str="A:B";
```

I want to split A & B using Struts2 tags and display individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Alexander Cogneau says or with String::split function

here is an example:

**java**

```
public String[] getSplittedString() {
    String str = "A:B";
    return str.split(":");
}
```

**interface**

```
<s:iterator value="splittedString" status="someSplittedString" var="string">
    <s:textfield name="splittedString" value="%{#string}"></s:textfield>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.indexOf() method to get the ":" and then use String.substring() to split the string at certain indexes. So in your case that would be something like this:

```
String str="A:B";
int position = str.indexOf(':');

String beginning = str.substring(0, position-1);
String end = str.substring(position);
```